# A better way to test if video or a 404 page?

Tags: php, video, curl, http-status-code-404

I am using the following code to see if a video is ready to embed on my site. It exits if the video is a 404 page and continues if it is anything else, including a video of course. Well, in theory.

I was confused for like an hour why it stopped working but it must be because the video is ready now and my code is trying to include the whole video in my code rather than just getting a header or something.

Is there a better way to do it please??

```
$url=$videourl;
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
  exit("video not ready!"); 
}

curl_close($handle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like you want to make a HEAD request. Use:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

Comment: Your instructions were not too clear but thanks for the help and it seems to be working so far. Although I had to take my option out and put yours in which wasn't clear from your instructions. Albeit you get a uptick from me.